# How to Find the Center of a Parallelogram

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

I want to find the center of a parallelogram in order to use it in my java program. I have four coordinates of the parallelogram and I want to find the center coordinate of the parallelogram. It seems I need to find the intersection point of the diagonal lines that I couldn't figure out of my poor math skills. Given four coordniates of the parallelogram what is the formula for finding the center of the parallelogram. I hope the intersection point of diagonals is the center of the parallelogram, correct me If it's not. If incase I'm wrong what I need is that intersection point not the center. It seems from another view point center of the bounding rectangle is the center of the parallelogram.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the intersection point of the diagonals. In fact, the diagonals bisect one another; so, if $(A,B)$ is one vertex and $(C,D)$ is the opposite, the center of the parallelogram is just $(\frac{A+C}{2}, \frac{B+D}{2}).$

Comment: yes, it worked. Math is great.

Comment: so, is it the formula for midpoint of a line. If so, is there any formula with out using trigonometry for finding a point at a certain distance from one of the end coordinates?

Comment: @pinkpanther If you want to go $t$ of the way from $(A,B)$ to $(C,D)$, with $t$ between $0$ and $1$, the formula is $(1-t)(A,B) + t(C,D)$.

Comment: cool thanks for that